# Consider the vector field $F(x,y,z) = \langle 2xyz {e}^{x^2y},z^2+x^2z {e}^{x^2y}, {e}^{x^2y} + 2yz-3z^2 \rangle$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

For ALL possible smooth curves $C$ initiating from the point $(0,-1,1)$ and ending at the point $(\sqrt{\ln(2)},1,1)$ evaluate $\int_C {F \cdot \ dr}$ Can someone help me find $F \cdot \ dr$ ? That would really help. Thanks.

Comment: Can you pls check for typos? I think the line integral will give zero between these two points.

Comment: I just edited. The last term that was the x^2 was a z^2. Sorry I will make sure that when I post something it will be free from typos.

Comment: No problem, it felt like there was a mismatch in the last term and if fixed, it would nicely turn out to be gradient of another function. With this, you avoid any integral etc. and the problem becomes more straightforward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please notice that $F(x,y,z)$ is gradient of function $f = z{e}^{x^2y} + yz^2 - z^3$

$\because$ $F(x,y,z) = \nabla f = \nabla(z{e}^{x^2y} + yz^2 - z^3)$

which tells you that the force is conservative and hence the work done between two points will be path independent.

Also according to gradient theorem, the work done by the force $F(x,y,z)$ as the object moves from point $A(0,-1,1)$ to point $B(\sqrt{\ln2},1,1)$ can be computed just by evaluating the function $f$ at each point.

$W = \int_C F \, dr = \int_C \nabla f \, dr = f(B) - f(A) = \displaystyle \big [z{e}^{x^2y} + yz^2 - z^3]_{(0,-1,1)}^{(\sqrt{\ln2},1,1)} = 3$.

As a side note, this is a conservative force and hence function $f$ is really potential energy. You are comparing potential energy at two points to find the work done.